# How to append a datarow of a df to another df top row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, datarow

I have a two df's

```
df1,
 key count
 one  2
 two  3



 df2,
 key count
 four 5
 five 6
```

I tried appending but it adds at the end,

My desired output should be,

```
 df,
 key  count
 one  2
 two  3
 four 5
 five 6
```

Comment: Can you show what you did that failed, also there is a dupe of this somewhere

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df1, df2])` ?

Comment: df1.join(df2, how='outer')

Comment: You can use df1.append(df2) since the dataframe structure is same. or df = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=0)

Comment: okay, thank you, How can I remove a column from a dataframe ?